# AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter chain in successfulAuthentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

Hello I have filter to get Autorization from JWT

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


public JwtAuthorizationFilter() {
    super("/**");
}

@Override
public void setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
    super.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
}


@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
     //code
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(getAuthentication(token));
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(String token) {
  // code
```

}

Problem is that when I reach successfulAuthentication and doing chain.doFilter I getting exception 
"servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed] with root cause"
And I can't get my endpoint. I also notice that authResult generate many (Objects?) with same data even if I login only once

@Edit I noticed now that, after successful authorize, spring trying to reach my controller few time. First return value but other just throw eceptions, and I don't know why I have this loop

Answer (score 0):

What is done inside `super.successfulAuthentication`? If you do any modification to `HttpServletResponse` object, e.g., by changing the Http Status Codes or `ResponseEntity` you won't be able to proceed to next filter in the chain by invoking `chain.doFilter(request, response)` anymore since the response is committed and returned to the client.